# container div wont stay on the side in a different resolution

Tags: html, css

so i have a div called "img-container-2" which needs to stay on the right side of the showcase div (opposite to "img-container-1") and its fine on my second monitor (which has a resolution of 1440x900) but on my main monitor (screen res: 1920x1080) the container isn't fully alinged on the right side of the showcase. Any help appreciated

```css
   /* Showcase 2 */
 .showcase-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #192534;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .text-container-2 {
  place-items: center;
  margin: 20px 70px 20px 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 .text-container-2 h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
 }

 .text-container-2 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
 }

 .img-container-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
 }

 .btn-secondary {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #cc224e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px black;
 }

 .btn-primary:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .img-container-2 {
  background: #3d5777;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  order: 2;
  margin-left: 200px;
 }

 .img-container-2 img {
  margin-right: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="showcase-2">
      <div class="img-container-2">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bNRTNr8/authenic-italian.png" alt="Photo of 
 2 pizzas on plates with glasses of water and cutlery on a table">
      </div>
      <div class="text-container-2">
        <h1>Authentic Italian Food</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis 
 voluptas inventore quae. Dolores sapiente officiis, reprehenderit fugiat 
 aliquam veritatis, distinctio doloremque minima facere maxime voluptatibus 
 sunt suscipit animi error molestias
          adipisci. Officia, quae adipisci quas quod incidunt, dolores vero 
 ipsa pariatur, necessitatibus ullam ea aspernatur eveniet quisquam eaque 
 molestiae.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt 
 praesentium reiciendis accusamus reprehenderit saepe accusantium vero quas 
 quam asperiores aliquam quia, laboriosam necessitatibus sequi autem aperiam 
 maxime quidem temporibus adipisci
          nemo minus doloremque possimus? Iste.</p>
        <button class="btn-secondary">View Our Menu</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `float` for a text-wrapper within a css-grid makes no sense at all espacially if the container should be aligned as a grid-card. Also `order` is a flex property not a grid property. The equivalent for CSS-Grid would be: `grid-area`.

Comment: ah sorry, the float must've been me leaving it in when i was messing around trying to fix it aha. and i also didnt know that order is a flex property lmao. i'm a beginner web dev and i only recently learnt css grid and flexbox so i must've got that knowledge muddled up. thanks for the help <3

Comment: on the mozilla mdn docs it says that order can be used in flex OR grid, so im guessing thats why the order did actually work aha https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image has not fitted to your container. So just apply styles to fit image:

```
.img-container-2 img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

An example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.showcase-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #192534;
  color: #fff;
}

.text-container-2 {
  place-items: center;
  margin: 20px 70px 20px 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-container-2 h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
}

.text-container-2 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.img-container-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.btn-secondary {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #cc224e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="showcase-2">
    <div class="img-container-2">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bNRTNr8/authenic-italian.png" alt="Photo of 2 pizzas on plates with glasses of water and cutlery on a table">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container-2">
      <h1>Authentic Italian Food</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis voluptas inventore quae. Dolores sapiente officiis, reprehenderit fugiat aliquam veritatis, distinctio doloremque minima facere maxime voluptatibus sunt suscipit animi error molestias
        adipisci. Officia, quae adipisci quas quod incidunt, dolores vero ipsa pariatur, necessitatibus ullam ea aspernatur eveniet quisquam eaque molestiae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt praesentium reiciendis accusamus reprehenderit saepe accusantium vero quas quam asperiores aliquam quia, laboriosam necessitatibus sequi autem aperiam maxime quidem temporibus adipisci
        nemo minus doloremque possimus? Iste.</p>
      <button class="btn-secondary">View Our Menu</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is mobile friendly design:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.showcase-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(420px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #192534;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .text-container-2 {
  place-items: center;
  margin: 20px 70px 20px 70px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 .text-container-2 h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
 }

 .text-container-2 p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
 }

 .img-container-2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
 }

 .btn-secondary {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #cc224e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px black;
 }

 .btn-primary:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .img-container-2 {
  background: #3d5777;
 }

 .img-container-2 img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="showcase-2">
    <div class="text-container-2">
      <h1>Authentic Italian Food</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis
        voluptas inventore quae. Dolores sapiente officiis, reprehenderit fugiat
        aliquam veritatis, distinctio doloremque minima facere maxime voluptatibus
        sunt suscipit animi error molestias
        adipisci. Officia, quae adipisci quas quod incidunt, dolores vero
        ipsa pariatur, necessitatibus ullam ea aspernatur eveniet quisquam eaque
        molestiae.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt
        praesentium reiciendis accusamus reprehenderit saepe accusantium vero quas
        quam asperiores aliquam quia, laboriosam necessitatibus sequi autem aperiam
        maxime quidem temporibus adipisci
        nemo minus doloremque possimus? Iste.</p>
      <button class="btn-secondary">View Our Menu</button>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container-2">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bNRTNr8/authenic-italian.png" alt="Photo of 2 pizzas on plates with glasses of water and cutlery on a table">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, just realised i hadn't included that part of my css in the question, will edit it right now :D (i had previously done what you recommended <3

Comment: @tylerlecho and what does not work? For me it works

Comment: Ahh ok, I seem to have fixed it. You're code worked a charm <3 I had some code under which was conflicting with the height. Thanks for your help <3 very appreciated

Comment: @tylerlecho thank you! :) I've added an example which is mobile friendly. Please, see my updated answer:).